# How to implement different workflows for a single api call in microservice architecture

Tags: java, microservices, workflows, orchestration

I am working on building a generic api that should ideally work with any data (Bring Your Own Data) but the overall functionality remains quite similar at the top level.

For example lets say we are building a generic recommendation system. Some clients might want to provide recommendation on books, some might want to do on movies, some might want to do on cloths, etc. The workflow required for each could differ based on the content type and/or client. I am wondering how should i wire the components in the system.

**Option 1**

Should the interfaces involved in my application be super generic like task and workflows as described in [Netflix Conductor](https://netflix.github.io/conductor/gettingstarted/basicconcepts/), where i can dynamically define workflow with bunch of existing tasks.

`void process(JsonObject json)` - read existing key value pairs from json input and add new information to the same payload that gets passed through the chain

If this type of generic workflow mechanism is so good and provides loose couple and high cohesion it should be quite popular. is that the case?

**Option 2**

Should i keep it little bit more typed like i pass a request object to a list of processors that would return me a decorated request object which i can execute against my datastore and do some post processing and return ?

`Request processRequest(Request request)` - takes original request and returns augmented request
`Response execute(Request request)` - executes the request
`Response processResponse(Response response)` - takes the basic response and returns augmented response

Here I am thinking of using dependency injection and have them wired up in different required combinations and then use the appropriate one depending on the request.

**Questions**

1. I am mainly curious to hear if highly generic solutions like Netflix conductor is widely adopted and used.
2. I have heard about Pipes and Filter architecture and can we call both options different implementations of Pipes and Filters or only option 1 can be called that way ?
3. I thought having clearly typed interfaces is better than very generic interfaces. Are there some examples of Pipes and Filter architecture with strict interface ?

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't know how much adopted is, but it's pretty sure that every B2B SaaS platform should deal with that kind of abstraction. When you build software that will be used from a single enterprise, you' ll have room to analyze and understand its domain and its behaviours, but when you build software for infinite, unknown enterprises, you have to find the minimum common factor between very different solutions that they want to apply to solve different problems
2. Pipes and filters is helpful when you have a set of well defined building block operations and you need to decide at runtime which operations to execute and in which order. It sounds like something similar to your case but first you have to understand how many degrees there are in the generic workflow and how to route a single message between the steps. You have a recommender system so

   - You work on *Resources* each one with an ID and a list of *Metadata*
   - Resources can have a finite number of *Types*, each type can be associated with a         different pre-processing step (eg. verify that a vinyl's label "Motown" exists, or if 1984 book belongs to category "books for children")
   - For each resource you calculate a ranking
   - For resources uploaded from stores you have a "publish output on ecommerce" step

As you can see, the plumbing between these steps can be driven from the same request content

3. If the value that you provide for customers is just to persist a bunh of data, you system doesn't need to know how the content of the data is made of. If you make sense of data through application of processing steps and algos, I suggest you to provide a schema-based API. for instance, As a customer I could define a specific resource type derived from base type, declaring which metadata are associated. In this case a resource is a list of tuples  and you can use that information to validate user inputs and sanitize them in order to don't break your processing pipeline

Too bad it's difficult to tell more without a deeper level of detail about domain and needed feature, but basically I think it's totally fine to abstract, even if a generic system is quite good at doing everything but not excellent in doing something